# What is the difference between metadata.FromOutgoingContext and metadata.FromIncomingContext?

Tags: go, grpc

If you are in a middle-ware that both receives the `context` and maybe append some data to `context` to send it to the next interceptor, then which of the two methods i.e. `metadata.FromOutgoingContext` and `metadata.FromIncomingContext` shall be called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are writing that middle-ware in the server, then you are **receiving** that metadata in the **incoming** request.

You should then use `metadata.FromIncomingContext` to get the metadata at that point.

The metadata in the "outgoing context" is the one generated by the client when **sending** an **outgoing** request to the server.

See here for examples of both:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md